# line of bash code from .configure file

Tags: bash, grep, configuration-files, pipe, head

I need to understand the following line of code:

```
BIN_DIR=`grep BIN_DIR= $SMLCM | head -1`
```

where `$SMLCH` contains a path

This is what I understood so far:

- `grep` will produce some string(s), possible paths. What does grep do with `BIN_DIR=`?
- the pathes are passed to head and all files within the paths will be used to extract their first line
- something is evaluated (what exactly?) and stored in `BIN_DIR`

Best regards,

Simon

Comment: This should not be a community wiki.

Comment: OK, but it is not possible to undo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will find all occureneces of the literal string "BIN_DIR=" in the file specified in the $SMLCM variable and only take the first line of that output and assign it to BIN_DIR.

Note that this may not work the way you want it to since whats gets assiggned to BIN_DIR is some string like "BIN_DIR=blah"  that is it may have the same effect as the following:

BIN_DIR="BIN_DIR=blah"

Answer (score 1):

- grep will match every line containing BIN_DIR= inside the contents of the file named by the var $SMLCM
- head will take the first line
- this line (the result of the commands inside the back ticks) is re-assigned to BIN_DIR

Answer (score 0):

This will extract **only** the value of `$BIN_DIR` the first time it appears in the file pointed to by `$SMLCM` and assign it to the variable `$BIN_DIR` in the current script:

```
BIN_DIR=$(sed -n 's/^BIN_DIR=\(.*\)$/\1/p' $SMLCM | head -n 1)
```

- `sed -n` : run the stream editor and don't print each line as it appears
- `s/` : substitute
- `^BIN_DIR=` : a line that begins ("^") with the text "BIN_DIR="
- `\(.*\)$` : and ends ("$") with a group ("\( \)") of zero or more ("*") of any characters (".")
- `/` : replace that match with
- `\1` : the contents of the first (in this case, only) group
- `/p` : finish the substitution and print the results